# How to determine angular velocity from a video?

Tags: python, image-processing, video-processing

Consider a video of a rotating wheel that has been read in as a grayscale. Within this video I have marked a Region of Interest:

[image]

Within the ROI I have taken a threshold on the pixel intensities: Every pixel with an intensity less than 50 is floored to 0 and every pixel with an intensity greater than 50 is scaled to 255.

From this information I have created a .txt-file with two columns: One contains a timestamp and the other contains the mean of the pixel-intensities within the ROI: [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AnN2vIxsA5VLiO0iNfwXGqIWwuhriw)

It should be possible to determine the angular velocity of the wheel from this information. But I am not sure as on how to do this. Does anyone have an idea?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 


VideoData = pd.read_csv('myData.txt', sep='\t')
VideoPixelMean = VideoData.iloc[:,1].values.tolist()
VideoTimestamp = VideoData.iloc[:,0].values.tolist()

SpokeList = []
for idx,el in enumerate(VideoPixelMean):
    if el >= 150:
        SpokeList.append(idx)
VideoVelocity=[]
VelocityTime = [0]
for idx,el in enumerate(SpokeList):
    if idx == 0:
        VideoVelocity.append(0)
    else:
        framesPassed = SpokeList[idx] - SpokeList[idx-1]
        if framesPassed > 2:
            velocity = 2*np.pi/360 * 72 * 50 * 30/framesPassed #each wheel has 5 spokes (the angle between two spokes is 72°) and a radius of 50mm; fps = 30
        else:
            velocity = 0
        VideoVelocity.append(velocity)
        velocityTime = VideoTimestamp[el]
        VelocityTime.append(velocityTime)
```

I am pretty sure the result is not correct though.

Comment: Is the speed constant and you plan to average over the whole time? Or are you expecting it to change dynamically?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Speed changes roughly every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem! Take my word with a grain of salt.

For our stationary ROI, the velocity can be determined by:

Measuring the time taken to get to the next spoke. To do this you can measure the first occurrence of a light pixel and the next occurrence of a light pixel, after encountering a dark pixel.

```
D-L-L-L-L-D-D-D.....D-L-L-L-L
  ^                   ^
```

When you identify these points, get the difference in time in seconds `(t)` to get the time passed.

Distance as you have calculated:

```
2π(r)(θ/360)
```

You can get the perpendicular velocity by:

```
v_perp = 2π(r)(θ/360) / t
```

Now you can divide it by `r` to get angular velocity:

```
v_angular = 2πθ/360t
```

```
spoke_start_time, spoke_end_time = None, None

for idx, pixel in enumerate(VideoPixelMean):
     if pixel > 150 and VideoPixelMean[idx-1] < 150:
            if not spoke_start_time:
                spoke_start_time = VideoTimestamp[idx]
            else:
                spoke_end_time = VideoTimestamp[idx]
                break
     else:
        last_pixel = 0

t = spoke_end_time - spoke_start_time # This should be in seconds

THETA = 72
v_angular = (2 * np.pi * THETA) / (360 * t)
```

Comment: Thx very much for your answer! I think your idea is very similar to mine though. And as it turns out, my idea has been working. I just typed in the wrong radius of the wheel.

Comment: Samaksh, do you know how to track the motion of one of the spokes from one frame to the following? From this, it should be possible to clalculate the angular displacement of the spoke. But I don't know how to track it..